# C# Creating Excel File - JET.OLEDB.4.0 and ACE.OLEDB.12.0 Output the Same Data Columns in Different Date Formats

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, oledbcommand

I've got something interesting happening, and I can't seem to find anything on it, though I *have* found some interesting information on similar cases.

I'm trying to create an Excel workbook on a server (which is Windows 2003 Server 32-bit) using only OLEDB and ADO.NET. (I tried ADO, but it didn't work at all - different story.) I'm using a CREATE TABLE statement to generate the Excel workbook and then I'm using an INSERT INTO statement to add the values to the spreadsheet.

The problem I'm having occurs on my development machine - a Windows 7 64-bit laptop. I have NOT moved this to the production environment (the server) yet.

The data I pull is stored in a datatable (System.Data), and comes from an MS Access database. The connection strings to the spreadsheet are different depending on whether I'm trying to create the newer format or the older one.

Here's the thing: When I use Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 as the provider, I get a spreadsheet which is unattractive to say the least, but has all the correct data in the correct formats. In particular, I'm speaking about *date* columns here - they're formatted as m/d/yyyy, which is correct.

When I use Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 as the provider, the date formats - from the *exact same datatable* - come in formatted as strings with format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.

I have no idea why the data isn't in the same format in both. I checked the datatable's datatype for one of the date columns, and it checks in as DateTime no matter which provider I use.

Here are the connection strings in use:

```
OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source={0}{1};" +
                                                                "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'", ssPth, ssXlsx));
```

The second is:

```
OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source={0}{1};" +
                                                                "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;';", ssPth, ssXls));
```

I use the exact same CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO statements with both versions. The OLEDB.4.0 spreadsheet comes out with dates in the date columns. The OLEDB.12.0 version doesn't.

Anyone have any ideas why this might be happening? While I can simply use the Jet provider, it's not able to create the xlsx-format of recent Excel versions. (It does, but there's the nasty warning message when opening.) But I can't use the newer version if the date columns are strings instead of dates.

I've tried adding "IMEX=1" as part of the Extended Properties section of the connection string and this causes an error during the execution of the INSERT INTO statement. Researching that error revealed removing the "IMEX=1" solves that problem, so I can't use that in the connection string.

I'm stumped as to how to handle this, and most of the posts here and in other forums I've read indicate how to solve this when the data is coming FROM Excel, but nothing I've found indicates why data from a database looks different going TO Excel.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not related to the solution you are using, but [Essential XlsIO](http://asp.syncfusion.com/demos/web/xlsio/externalconnection.aspx) can generate Excel documents and you could achieve your requirement. [Free community license](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) available.